# Spring Boot: How to use Bootstrap 4 WebJar SASS files

Tags: spring-boot, maven, sass, bootstrap-4, webjars

I am trying to use the Bootstrap 4.4.1 webjar in a spring boot project. However i am not able to access the bootstrap/scss directory to include it into a test sass file. Are there any ways to fix this/workarounds?